# QField - How to enforce text with a pattern

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am setting up QField to capture data in the field and the users will be collecting samples. All sample ID's follow the same naming convention: The letters AB followed by 4 numbers (e.g. AB1234.)

Is there a way to enforce a constraint where a value outside of this convention (e.g. AB123) cannot be entered?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In Layer-Properties_Attribute-Form, highlight the attribute you want to constrain, e.g. ID. In the right hand pane, you will see options for the attribute, one of which is constraints. In Exression (under Constraints) you need to enter a statement to constrain. I suggest usng RegExp. This is not my stong point, but something like:

```
regexp_match('ID', [A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}) > 0
```

[Also see QGIS manual here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#attributes-form-properties)

As an aside. This is an ID column. It may be approrpriate to make this an autonumber or sequence field. I note your ID is comprised of two letters and four numbers. Do the letters mean anything? Can this be a seperate field, perhaps a drop down. Then an autonumber field, which you can format to be a 4 digit integer. You can then concatenate the fields together later.